# How to Flip the POSES?

Tags: animation, armature

I have been doing a Reloading animation and when I finally finished I wanted to flip the way the reloading goes, just flip the *Poses*, not the *Animation*. See Images Below:

What I **HAVE** and what I **WANT**

[image]

I though the "*Flip Animation Addon*" could help, but it didn't do what I wanted.

**I just want to keep the *First and Last 2 poses of animation* and the rest poses in between should be Flipped.**

[image]

Comment: Also something I want to mention is that, if you will be trying to make it in my file you might get into some problems as the gun is parented to the Left Thumb 1, you would have to change it to Right Thumb 1 and propably possition it accordingly. and also the parent of the Mag would have to be changed

Comment: if your armature is symmetrical, you can [ctrl]+[c, [ctrl]+[shift]+[v]